# What does this do? (Assembly Code) Accessing Array Index

Tags: assembly, x86

So I'm learning basic assembly code right now and was wondering what this does ...

```
mov eax, dword ptr[esi+4*ebx]
```

So I know that eax is the targeted register that we'll be moving information into. Dword is double word, and a word is ... 16 bytes long I believe (words are 8 bytes). What does the `esi + 4 * ebx` stand for? `enter code here`

This is the code ....

[image: Code]

Comment: @boiler96 has already answered your question. I'll just add that, in the context of the rest of the code, `mov eax, dword ptr[esi+4*ebx]` is akin to `eax = arr1[i]`, since `esi` holds the base address of the array and `ebx` is used as an index. The `*4` is used since each element in `arr1` is 4 bytes in size.

Comment: Stop programming by belief. Programming is not a religion. A word is not 8 bytes, whether it was in the beginning or not. Look things up, don't assume.

Comment: ... "enter code here" followed by an image. Quite ironic, I believe.

Comment: @KerrekSB: I agree with "stop programming by belief". But ISTM that programming is, for many, a religion alright.

Answer (score 1):

This instruction takes the contents of ebx, multiplies this by 4, and adds the contents of esi to the result.  This value is treated like a pointer into memory.  Four bytes of memory at this location are loaded and placed in eax.

In x86, The dword datatype is 32 bits (4 bytes), and words are 16 bits (2 bytes).

Comment: And by contents you mean the array? Can you give me an example when ESI = {2,4,6} and EBX = {6,8,10}

Comment: _"Can you give me an example when ESI = {2,4,6} and EBX = {6,8,10}"_. Huh? `EBX` isn't pointing to an array in the code you've shown. It's used as an index starting at 0 and going up to `len`.

Comment: An array is just a contiguous piece of memory, and each of the entries has its own address, at conscutive addresses. To fetch into the array, you calculate the address of the entry. In this case, that is `[esi+4*ebx]`.

Comment: @Xari: There are some guides / other links in the x86 tag wiki page.  http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info.  Also info on using gdb on asm code, displaying regs changed by an instruction.  That should help you see what instructions do as you step through code.